# Notification not sending to facebook friend

Tags: javascript, facebook, notifications, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created an application where i am trying to invite friends via facebook invite friends js method but all working fine but no notification sent to that friend.

My Application Link: http://www.huzoorbux.com/fl/app/android/www/homepage_nopost.html

My Code:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
        <script>
        FB.api(
    "/me/invitable_friends",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
        if(top.location != self.location) {
                top.location = self.location
            }
            FB.init({
                appId:'228877127299395',
                cookie:true,
                status:true,
                xfbml:true
            });

            function FacebookInviteFriends()
            {
                FB.ui({
                    method: 'apprequests',
                    message: 'Join My Job Buddy'
                });
            }
        </script>

<a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();"><div class="connectbutton5" id="ol">Invite Friends</div></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

App Requests are for games only, that may be the reason. And always use a callback function for error handling, maybe you are missing an error:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'YOUR_MESSAGE_HERE'
}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

Also:

> The invitable_friends API is only available for games that have a Facebook Canvas app implementation using version 2.0 of the Graph API.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.1

If you want to invite someone to a website, use the Send and Share Dialogs and Buttons. You don´t even need to authorize the user for them.